# Weird limit of a product $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3n+1}{3n}\frac{3n+2019+1}{3n+2019}...\frac{3n+2019n+1}{3n+2029n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

I want to evaluate the following limit:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{3n+1}{3n}\frac{3n+2019+1}{3n+2019}...\frac{3n+2019n+1}{3n+2029n} $$

The general term of the product is:
$$ \frac{3n+2019k+1}{3n+2019k}$$
Its limit seems to be one. Writing the initial limit as:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=0}^n\frac{(3n+2019k+1)}{(3n+2019k)} $$
I concluded that the limit would be 1. To my surprise, the answer seems to be $ \sqrt[2019]{674} $, which is very close to 1, though not the same thing.

This question was part of a highschool grade 12 competition. Can someone explain what my mistake is? Was I correct when reversing the limit and the product?

Thank you!

Comment: $1^{\infty} \neq 1$, it's indeterminate.

Comment: no you cant always reverse limits and products

Comment: I see. I thought about writing the terms as (1+1/n)^n, but I'm not sure how to deal with the product.

Comment: @Wolfuryo what standard of maths are you at? that limit should jump out at you...

Comment: @Wolfuryo, do you know Riemann sums?

Comment: @Atticus, Yes, though it didn't cross my mind to try using them here.

Comment: @It'sNotALie, I'm not quite sure

Comment: You are not in the good time slot ! Change everywhere 2019 into 2020, the problem will appear under a new light :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=0}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+2019k}\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\operatorname{exp}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+2019k}\right)\right)$$

So we evaluate the limit without the exponential:

$$
\begin{aligned}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{3n+2019k}\right)&=
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{3n+2019k}\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{3+2019\frac{k}{n}}\\
&= \int_{0}^1\frac{1}{3+2019x}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2019}\ln 674
\end{aligned}
$$

and from the exponential you get the result $\sqrt[2019]{674}$.

**Edit:** The step where I pass from $\ln\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3n+2019k}\right)$ to $\dfrac{1}{3n+2019k}$ is based on:

$$x-x^2\leq \ln(1+x)\leq x$$

summing, and squeezing.

Comment: I was about to ask about the logarithm when I noticed the edit. I'll see if I can work out the problem by myself and mark your answer as accepted once I'm finished. Thank you!

Comment: Alrighty, it all seems to check out. Thanks for your help! I'll remember the trick to turn the product into a sum using the exponential :)

Comment: @Wolfuryo, You're welcome :)